# convert days to weeks in SQL server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table whose only date fields are smalldatetime and DOW (day of week 1=Sunday).

I need to aggregate these days for weekly averages for specific week/year combinations (without hours and minutes per below script).

How can I convert the smalldate and DOW into a year and week#?  I have a table I can link to that uses Saturday (DOW 7) as a WeekEndDate that I could link to if I could get that far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For example this statement provides the below results:

```
select a.LOB_Code, a.store, day, DOW, hour, minutes, (sum(NetTrans)/1.000)sumNetTrans

from facts.Store_Day_TransBy30 a

inner join facts.Stores b on a.Store = b.Store

where A.store = 8169 and DAY between '1/3/2016' and '1/4/2016' 

group by a.LOB_Code, a.store, day, DOW, hour, minutes

order by a.LOB_Code, a.store, day, DOW, hour, minutes
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqyvd.png)

Comment: You would need to give an example of the data you have and the data you want to derive from it.

Comment: Look here on how to post a question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data (preferably as DDL+DML statements) and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I assume day column is of datatype, here is the query which may help you.

```
SELECT
    a.LOB_Code, 
    a.store, 
    day,
    DOW, 
    hour, 
    minutes, 
    (sum(NetTrans)/1.000)sumNetTrans,
    YEAR([day]) AS Year#,
    DATEPART(WK,[day]) AS Week#

from facts.Store_Day_TransBy30 a

inner join facts.Stores b on a.Store = b.Store

where A.store = 8169 and DAY between '1/3/2016' and '1/4/2016' 

group by a.LOB_Code, a.store, day, DOW, hour, minutes,YEAR([day]),DATEPART(WK,[day])

order by a.LOB_Code, a.store, day, DOW, hour, minutes
```

Comment: SandeshP, thank you for this. The overall idea would be to remove day, dow, hour, minutes from the results to get a weekly average - summing up and averaging 7 days at a time - somehow creating virtual weeks.

Comment: I'm envisioning a case statement that figures out a 1:7 sequence and adds them together but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I believe we need to calculate week number/ day of week. So if "day" is column from your table then we can use SQL Server inbuilt function to get week number/ day of week. DATEPART(WK,[day]) -- Week Number & DATEPART(DW,Day) -- Day of Week

Comment: the problem is that our fiscal year 2016 week 1 was Jan3-Jan9 (Sun-Sat: 1:7)

Answer (score 0):

Also here is the another query with temp table and manually generated data. It's always recommended to provide some sample data to get hold off complete picture.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE DemoTable
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
DateCreated SMALLDATETIME,
DOW TINYINT NOT NULL, -- This can be generated runtime(DATEPART(DW,date column)) but as your table contain thsi column I've purposefully added here.
TmpCount INT NOT NULL -- Random column used for aggregation
)

-- Populate some records 

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE='2015-01-01'

WHILE @CurrentDate <='2016-12-31'
BEGIN

    INSERT DemoTable
    (
        DateCreated,
        DOW,
        TmpCount
    )
    SELECT
        @CurrentDate AS DateCreated,
        DATEPART(DW,@CurrentDate) AS DOW,
        ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 6) + 1 AS TmpCount

    SET @CurrentDate=DATEADD(dd,1,@CurrentDate)
END

-- Retrieve aggregated data 
SELECT 
    YEAR(DateCreated) AS Year#
    ,DATEPART(WK,DateCreated) AS Week#
    ,SUM(TmpCount) AS TmpSum 
FROM DemoTable
GROUP BY YEAR(DateCreated),DATEPART(WK,DateCreated)
ORDER BY 1,2
-- Drop Table

DROP TABLE DemoTable
```

Comment: Wow - this is beyond my ability to understand. Unfortunately I do not have authority to create tables on our corporate sql servers. But thanks for spending the time to create that. It looks impressive.